# Connect two arduinos & ethernet shields to internet

Tags: networking, arduino, arduino-uno, ethernet, lan

I have two Arduinos (Uno R3) with two Ethernet Shields (HanRun HR911105A). I need to connect them over internet, I plug one Arduino Uno (with Ethernet Shield) to my Laptop (RJ45), and one other Arduino Uno (with Ethernet Shield too) plug to managed Switch. The goal is, I want to connect my laptop/PC to internet through them (two Arduino with each Ethernet Shield). So, what am I supposed to do?

Please help, Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send internet packets between two Arduinos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386864/how-to-send-internet-packets-between-two-arduinos)

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are trying to accomplish? 
I'm going to assume you want the arduino to be able to communicate with one another (like a ping). In that case that is quite simple:

- You connect the two arduinos to a router (if you want them to be in
  the same network).
- Run Ethernet>DHCPAddressPrinter example. Your arduinos should then be
  allocated IP addresses by the router.

If you don't want to use a router, you could try the following solutions:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/connecting-ethernet-shield-to-computer

Comment: Thank you for answering, I wanna try to make my laptop can ping to the network through two arduinos with each ethernet shield. The scenario that I used is: Laptop --> 1 Arduino with Eth. Shield --> 1 Arduino with Eth. shield --> managed Switch. What should I do? Thank You..